# Grails Mac OSX Install via Brew Restarting terminal

Tags: macos, grails, terminal

I've been trying to get past step one of installing grails, which is bad i know. But the issue im having is getting grails to work via the OSX terminal. similar to node using brew I type the command

`brew install grails`

this retrieves grails and installs it, simple. to see if its installed correctly you type `grails -version`

However when i do that it's as though my terminal restarts. Its a hard thing to describe so here is a link to a youtube video that shows you what happens. I have JAVA installed and working. Anyone have an idea?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ButLwGfBTZo

Comment: [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/) instead of brew can make the process easier.

Comment: Use GVM for Groovy and Grails development, not Brew.

Comment: Having said that, that is indeed a very odd error.

Comment: Just FYI, I'm using grails 2.4.3 via homebrew on OS X just fine, looks like something specific to your machine. Anything interesting come up when you run `brew doctor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this is the first excursion I have had into any Java related development. I made a rookie mistake and was unaware of vital piece of information. You do not need Java to run Grails you need the Java Development Kit (JDK). Which is a different thing completely apparently.
Available here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Once installed run this command in the terminal `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` This will show you all of the current Java Virtual Machines installed. In my case

`Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.0_11, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home`

You then need to set your JAVA_HOME Environment variable to point to your JVM. Like so `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` use /usr/libexec/java_home rather than the true location as this will specifi the version set in Java Preferences for the current user. The source for that nice little trick is here http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/

Once you've done that you can type the command `brew install grails` or `gvm install grails` which is what i should probably use rather than brew as "SurrealAnalysis" rightly pointed out in one of the answers.

moment of truth `grails -version` and i got a response `Grails version: 2.4.3`... sweet.

Thank you all for the replies and help.

Comment: Glad to see your issue was resolved. You should accept your own answer when you can, as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3):

Following previous post, GVM it is not available in Homebrew, because of [this](https://github.com/gvmtool/gvm-cli/issues/266).

GDK is also now officially [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/).

So, the steps would be:

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "/Users/{YOUR_USER_NAME}/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk install groovy
```

Hope it helps! :)